# Search or List all open PRs across multiple specific repositories

Tags: github

Is there any way to search for open PRs across multiple repositories in GitHub?

I tried to search by tags, and that does not work.  Does not seem like you can wildcard the repo name, or list multiple repos.

The only thing we could come up with is to create a tag in all our repos and search by that tag.

Comment: Is there an issue with doing multiple queries?

Comment: We have 16 repositories and growing in a org of over 500 repos.  So yah one search query would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically or via their API.
E.g. from Octokit you can go:

```cs
var result = await gitHubClient.Search.SearchIssues(new SearchIssuesRequest
{
    Is = new [] {IssueIsQualifier.PullRequest, IssueIsQualifier.Open}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best we've been doing is just listing them out in a single query. Example:

```
is:open is:pr repo:<repo 1> repo:<repo 2> repo:<repo 3> archived:false draft:false
```

Answer (score -1):

To anyone who ends up here
you can use qualifiers in the search box on the top left
example: `author:<yourusername> is:pr`

this will list all your prs

and you can do more, a list of qualifiers is here
https://help.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests

:) happy coding